# Populate an object with razor properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, razor

I'm trying to populate an object and push this into an array.
Problem 1: My array gets the correct amount of objects but every object has the same value as the last entry.
Problem 2: I can't declare a new object inside my foreach loop in razor.

These are 2 examples of what I've tried so far in my code

```
var object = {
Name:"",
Adress:""
};
var objArray=[];
@await foreach (var person in Model)
{
    @:object.Name:"@person.Name";
    @:object.Adress:"@person.Adress";
    @:objArray.push(object);
}
```

I tried declaring the object inside the foreach but that doesn't seem to work.

```
@await foreach (var person in Model)
{
    @:var object ={
       @:Name:"@person.Name",
       @:Adress:"@person.Adress"
};
```

If I remove var it says I need an identifier. But if I leave var it tries to push var with the object inside my array.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by Creating an object with arrays for name and adresss inside and pushing to the data inside the array.

```js
var obj = {
 Name:[],
    Adress:[]
};

obj.Name.push("Name1");
obj.Name.push("Name2");
obj.Adress.push("Adress1");
obj.Adress.push("Adress2");
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.Name[1]);
console.log(obj.Adress[1]);
```